# Custom UITableView Cell's Y offset not editable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode-storyboard

I've inherited a project which makes use of custom UITableView cells. I'm normally fine to deal with them, but in this specific case I have one which seems to have a Y offset of 434px, but that magic number doesn't exist anywhere in code, the storyboard's location of the view is greyed out and I can't move it.

[image: Cell options in the storyboard attribute inspector. Clicking elsewhere on the square there doesn't unlock anything.]

[image: the cell itself - nothing special - though I want to move it down further]

Comment: Is your cell is too big??

Comment: I'm not sure what would constitute that, it renders perfectly and has the same width as the parent table (not you can change that, I think?).

I just need to change its Y location.

Answer (score 0):

There was a view higher in the UITableView's hierarchy whose height (editable) was controlling the location of the start of the prototype cells.